# Override Primefaces Renderer

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I'm developing a dynamic menu using Primefaces and JSF 2.2.

The problem is that it's not inserting the menu id. Looking primefaces' code it hits a code that will always be false:

BaseMenuRenderer:

```
protected boolean shouldRenderId(MenuElement element) {
    if(element instanceof UIComponent)
        return shouldWriteId((UIComponent) element);
    else
        return false;
}
```

TieredMenuRenderer:

```
 writer.startElement("li", null);
                    if(shouldRenderId(submenu)) {
                        writer.writeAttribute("id", submenu.getClientId(), null);
                    }
```

So, I decided to override primefaces' TieredMenuRenderer, but my override constructor classe is called but the override method is never called.

Here's how I set my facesconfig.xml

```
<render-kit>
        <renderer>
            <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
            <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.TieredMenuRenderer</renderer-type>
            <renderer-class>ui.jsf.TieredMenuRenderer</renderer-class>
        </renderer>
    </render-kit>
```

My override class:

```
    public class TieredMenuRenderer extends org.primefaces.component.tieredmenu.TieredMenuRenderer {
  @Override
    protected void encodeElements(FacesContext context, AbstractMenu menu, List<MenuElement> elements) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("----------- TEST --------------");
        super.encodeElements(context, menu, elements);
    }
```

Sysout is never print.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Edit:

Add ID to DefaultMenuItem:

```
  DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem();
  item.setId(menuItem.getMenuId());// just return a string value.
```

Adding menu xhtml, the "menucontroller.model" is a primefaces MenuModel which I use a DefaultMenuModel :

Iterating over renderer kit, When I execute the following command, returns the correct renderer-type `org.primefaces.component.TieredMenuRenderer`

```
Iterator<String> renderKit = kit.getRendererTypes("org.primefaces.component");
```

When I execute the following code returns my qualified classname `ui.jsf.TieredMenuRenderer@64baec0e`:

```
Renderer renderer = kit.getRenderer("org.primefaces.component", "org.primefaces.component.TieredMenuRenderer");
```

Comment: Does the package "ui.jsf.TieredMenuRenderer" match the package of your class? Also, does the method signature of your method match exactly?

Comment: Yes. My class I use "copy qualified name" from eclipse IDE. And method I use autocomplete to override.

Comment: Ah, I think I just noticed that your renderer-type class name and the class name you're extending, don't match packages.  In the facesconfig.xml you're missing ".tieredmenu" in your package path.

Comment: in All examples i found this way. Also, i copied this renderer-type from primefaces' faces-config.xml  itself. But I'll give a try...

Comment: Didn't work. Still not calling overrided method

Comment: You can verify that your renderer is actually registered by getting the view's renderkit and iterating over the renders for this component family: https://javaserverfaces.java.net/docs/2.2/javadocs/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getRenderKit()
But for your original problem, were you setting the IDs programmatically in the xhtml or expecting them to be auto-generated?

Comment: Just edited my post with more details. Complemeting, it's not adding my created ID nor autogenerating one.

Comment: I'd say since your renderer is indeed registered then either your menu is empty, the component that you're using isn't using that renderer, or system.out is going somewhere other than where you expect (which is easy to test by throwing a runtime exception instead).

Comment: how could I confirm that i'm overriding the right renderer? Because I can debug and this class (tieredMenuRenderer) is called...

Comment: Check actually used renderer when `javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.getRenderer(FacesContext)` gets called for your menu.

Comment: Your faces-config is in WAR, right, not in another JAR in WAR/WEB-INF/lib? Otherwise `<ordering>` needs to be specified.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me to find the correct renderer which I should override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, My renderer was not overriding the correct renderer. I was overriding `org.primefaces.component.tieredmenu.TieredMenuRenderer` when I should override `org.primefaces.component.MenubarRenderer`.

Then, to correct the primefaces id problem I did the following in my rendered class:

```
 @Override
    protected boolean shouldRenderId(MenuElement element) {
        return true;
    }

@Override
    public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        AbstractMenu menu = (AbstractMenu) component;
        encodeMarkup(context, menu);
        encodeScript(context, menu);
    }
```

EncodedEnd was calling "generateIds()" from primefaces which override my ids.

Full rendered class:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.component.menu.AbstractMenu;
import org.primefaces.model.menu.MenuElement;

public class MenuRenderer extends org.primefaces.component.menubar.MenubarRenderer {

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldRenderId(MenuElement element) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        AbstractMenu menu = (AbstractMenu) component;
        encodeMarkup(context, menu);
        encodeScript(context, menu);
    }

}
```